# Need help for an algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I know I should not ask this, but I really need help for developing a little algorithm for my program in java.
Here's the problem:
I have this kind of array:

```
// note that {1, 1} is present twice, is duplicated
int[][] array = {{0, 1}, {0, 2}, {1, 1}, {3, 5}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}};
```

And I want to get out of this 2 different arrays :

```
int[][] norepetition = {{0,1},{0,2},{3,5},{2,2}};
int[][] withrepetition = {{1,1}};
```

The function should seperate the initial array into 2 new arrays, one containing the coordinates that aren't repeated and another who contains the coordinates that come multiple times.

I've thought of using a for-loop and go through each coordinates and copying it into a new table A after checking if there's already the same coordinate (by doing a for-loop again)... but I'm looking for an easier/better way (the base array is very long and I'm afraid my technic isn't much optimized).

Thank you!

Comment: which version of java?

Comment: Could you maybe improve your question title? It'd make your question easier to understand at first glance.

Comment: If you don't care about the order of the elements, you should look at `Set` and `HashSet`.

Comment: @Vellyxeya, the lines you provide do not compile

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson ok I looked at Set and HashSet and I found an example with Integer, but here I have a 2 dimension array, is it also possible to use it? And sorry I didn't know what to write for the title

Comment: You could take your "Pair" of integers and turn them into a class. Then you could create a `Set<Pair>` that stores them how you'd like.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Use a HashMap and you can do it in O(N) runtime...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;

public class StackQ2 {

    static class IntContainer {
        public IntContainer(int a, int b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }
        int a;
        int b;

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
                return false;

            IntContainer that = (IntContainer) o;

            if (a != that.a) return false;
            return b == that.b;

        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int result = a;
            result = 31 * result + b;
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "{" + a + "," + b + "}";
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<IntContainer> array = Arrays.asList(
                new IntContainer(0, 1),
                new IntContainer(0, 2),
                new IntContainer(1, 1),
                new IntContainer(3, 5),
                new IntContainer(1, 1),
                new IntContainer(2, 2)
        );
        List<IntContainer>  norepetition = new ArrayList<>();
        Set<IntContainer> withrepetition = new HashSet<>();
        for (IntContainer element : array) {
            if (Collections.frequency(array, element) > 1) {
                withrepetition.add(element);
            } else {
                norepetition.add(element);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("NoRep: " +Arrays.toString(norepetition.toArray()));
        System.out.println("Rep: " +Arrays.toString(withrepetition.toArray()));

    }
```

**output**:

```
NoRep: [{0,1}, {0,2}, {3,5}, {2,2}]
Rep: [{1,1}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your code man!

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to use java streams, below is what you can do.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class JavaStreams {

  public static void main(String argv[])
  {
      Stream<Integer[]> stream = Stream.of( new Integer[][]{{0, 1}, {0, 2}, {1, 1}, {3, 5}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}});
      List<Integer[]> matching = stream.filter(i -> i[0] == i[1]).collect(Collectors.toList());
      Stream<Integer[]> notmatchingstream = Stream.of( new Integer[][]{{0, 1}, {0, 2}, {1, 1}, {3, 5}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}});
      List<Integer[]> notmatching = notmatchingstream.filter(i -> i[0] != i[1]).collect(Collectors.toList());

      System.out.println("Matching Integer arrays are: ");
      matching.stream().forEach(p -> System.out.println(p[0]+", "+p[1])) ;
      System.out.println("Not Matching Integer arrays are: ");
      notmatching.stream().forEach(p -> System.out.println(p[0]+", "+p[1])) ;

  }

}
```

Comment: Changing input from `int[][]` to `Integer[][]` may not be appropriate.